# "Talking About This" from the graph Insights API for pages that I am not the owner of

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to access the "Talking About This" metric from the Insights API?

I believe it is the page_storytellers object. However, if I try it I get a message saying I need to be the page owner to access it. The data is available for the public to view as "Talking about this". So, I guess it is publicly available information.

Is there any way to get to it through the API if you are not the owner or admin of the page? If not, is there any plans on making it available with a regular user_token just like the "application_active_users" metric that is available with a regular user_token.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this question over here:
[How to access FB Page's new metric "are talking about this"? FQL? Graph?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7679021/how-to-access-fb-pages-new-metric-are-talking-about-this-fql-graph/8191082#8191082)

tl;dr: They just added it to the graph API.  It is called: "talking_about_count".